# Is it possible to change resolution?

Tags: sid-meiers-simgolf

I am currently playing SimGolf and appears that the game only runs in a resolution of 800x600 - I do not see an option to change screen resolution or to run the game in windowed mode.

Is it possible to change the resolution that the game runs in to either 1920x1080 fullscreen or a windowed mode?

Comment: I seem to recall playing it in a larger resolution. Can't tell you how though.

Comment: I assume you're referring to [Sid Meier's SimGolf](http://www.mobygames.com/game/sid-meiers-simgolf) from 2002, not the similarly named Maxis title [SimGolf](http://www.mobygames.com/game/simgolf) from 1996?

Comment: Yes - the 2002 version, I will retag accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - it's not possible to change the resolution the game is played at using any method in game. I wasn't able to find any alternative way to change the resolution via any resolution switchers or changing configuration files.

In the end, in order to play the game at a custom resolution I installed the game within a virtual machine, and then resized the virtual machine to the size I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [DxWnd](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/2-ways-force-directx-applications-launch-windowed-fullscreen-windows/)
to force the game to run in non-fullscreen. I tried this tool for a while. It ran Sid Meier's Golf in non-fullscreen.

The only thing I can't figure out yet is how to get the windowed mode buttons on it. The nice thing about this tool is that you can specify the x and y coords for the window (left bottom in settings). I haven't succeeded in getting the window to drag yet though.

Perhaps the virtualization method described above is the best idea. Less fuss and you have control over the window unlike that DxWnd tool.

Comment: Running SimGolf through DXWnd fails for me with `CreateProcess "C:\Users\stevo\Downloads\sim_golf\sim golf\Sid Meier's SimGolf\golf.exe" 
error=740`